# How to migrate MUI _document.js and _app.js to next.js13 app/layout.js

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I found these documents ([_document.js](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js), [_app.js](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js)) but it is not so clear to me how it should be defined.

This is the layout.js file I started building, Is there something missing, or something that needs fixing?

Thanks.

`app/layout.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import theme, { roboto } from '../utility/theme'
import Head from './Head'
import createEmotionCache from '../utility/createEmotionCache'

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache()

export default function RootLayout({ children }, props) {
  const { Component, cache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props

  return (
    <html className={roboto.className}>
      <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Component {...pageProps}>{children}</Component>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </CacheProvider>
    </html>
  )
}

RootLayout.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  emotionCache: PropTypes.object,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```